# How can I make Spark Streaming count the words in a file in a unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I've successfully built a very simple Spark Streaming application in Java that is based on the [HdfsCount example in Scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.1/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/HdfsWordCount.scala).

When I submit this application to my local Spark, it waits for a file to be written to a given directory, and when I create that file it successfully prints the number of words. I terminate the application by pressing Ctrl+C.

Now I've tried to create a very basic unit test for this functionality, but in the test I was not able to print the same information, that is the number of words.

What am I missing?

Below is the unit test file, and after that I've also included the code snippet that shows the countWords method:

## StarterAppTest.java

```
import com.google.common.io.Files;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;


import org.junit.*;

import java.io.*;

public class StarterAppTest {

  JavaStreamingContext ssc;
  File tempDir;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    ssc = new JavaStreamingContext("local", "test", new Duration(3000));
    tempDir = Files.createTempDir();
    tempDir.deleteOnExit();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    ssc.stop();
    ssc = null;
  }

  @Test
  public void testInitialization() {
    Assert.assertNotNull(ssc.sc());
  }


  @Test
  public void testCountWords() {

    StarterApp starterApp = new StarterApp();

    try {
      JavaDStream<String> lines = ssc.textFileStream(tempDir.getAbsolutePath());
      JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = starterApp.countWords(lines);

      ssc.start();

      File tmpFile = new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath(), "tmp.txt");
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(tmpFile, "UTF-8");
      writer.println("8-Dec-2014: Emre Emre Emre Ergin Ergin Ergin");
      writer.close();

      System.err.println("===== Word Counts =======");
      wordCounts.print();
      System.err.println("===== Word Counts =======");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Assert.assertTrue(true);

  }

}
```

This test compiles and starts to run, Spark Streaming prints a lot of diagnostic messages on the console but the call to `wordCounts.print()` does not print anything, whereas in StarterApp.java itself, they do.

I've also tried adding `ssc.awaitTermination();` after `ssc.start()` but nothing changed in that respect. After that I've also tried to create a new file manually in the directory that this Spark Streaming application was checking but this time it gave an error.

For completeness, below is the wordCounts method:

```
public JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> countWords(JavaDStream<String> lines) {
    JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
      @Override
      public Iterable<String> call(String x) { return Lists.newArrayList(SPACE.split(x)); }
    });

    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(
            new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
              @Override
              public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) { return new Tuple2<>(s, 1); }
            }).reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);

    return wordCounts;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few pointers:

- Give at least 2 cores to SparkStreaming context. 1 for the Streaming and 1 for the Spark processing. "local" -> "local[2]"
- Your streaming interval is of 3000ms, so somewhere in your program you need to wait -at least- that time to expect an output.
- Spark Streaming needs some time for the setup of listeners. The file is being created immediately after `ssc.start` is issued. There's no warranty that the filesystem listener is already in place. I'd do some `sleep(xx)` after `ssc.start`

In Streaming, it's all about the right timing.

Comment: Hello Gerard, I've made it use 2 cores, decreased the interval to 0.5 seconds, and added a Thread.sleep for 3 seconds: https://gist.github.com/emres/67b4eae86fa92df69f61 However, running this version still did not print any word counts as can be seen in the output at http://pastebin.com/AE2hTZbS Therefore I cannot understand whether it actually processed the file and counted the words. In the output there are lines such as "Finding new files took 82 ms", but I don't know whether this means it found and processed them.

Comment: Hi Emre, try reducing the first sleep to 1sec and adding another sleep(6s) after the file.close

Comment: I did what you've suggested ([see new version](https://gist.github.com/emres/67b4eae86fa92df69f61)) but I still don't see the words counted [in the output](http://pastebin.com/VKf6yzs0). Though your suggestion seems very similar to what is done at the end of [this example](https://github.com/databricks/spark-perf/blob/master/streaming-tests/src/main/scala/streaming/perf/HdfsRecoveryTest.scala). This really seems very very time-sensitive indeed.

Comment: I think you have other issues. I see this error 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.hash.HashFunction.hashInt(I)'  probably at the point where data is being processed. This is probably related to a guava version conflict.

Comment: Hats off to your perseverance! Based on your feedback I've added [this Guava dependency explicitly to my pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/emres/ba7ad991406595c78db0), and ran the same unit test, this time to see [the output I've expected](http://pastebin.com/QTrdZ7Uz). Probably Spark submit script was taking care of this Guava conflict for the application, but unit tests, not using the submit script, are prone to such issues.  I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Saved me a lot of time!

Comment: With this code I just get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Adding new inputs, transformations, and output operations after starting a context is not supported` on the second call to `wordCounts.count();` after the streaming session has been started. Could you post a complete answer?