# How to unit test Spark Streaming code?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-1.6

I use the latest Spark 1.6.0.

Looked at another stackoverflow post [How can I make Spark Streaming count the words in a file in a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356157/how-can-i-make-spark-streaming-count-the-words-in-a-file-in-a-unit-test)

I am trying to use the sample @ https://gist.github.com/emres/67b4eae86fa92df69f61  have for writing a sample unit test for spark. I intend to write a unit test after that for my actual spark application. However, I am unable to use the example @ https://gist.github.com/emres/67b4eae86fa92df69f61. This gives me error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Adding new inputs, transformations,
>   and output operations after starting a context is not supported at
>   oracle.security.ti.reportgenerator.test.StarterAppTest.testCountWords(StarterAppTest.java:62)

Any ideas how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Please include the code you use that leads to the issue in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do [wordCounts.print()](https://gist.github.com/emres/67b4eae86fa92df69f61#file-starterapptest-java-L59) on [JavaPairDStream wordCounts](https://gist.github.com/emres/67b4eae86fa92df69f61#file-starterapptest-java-L43) after [you have started streaming context](https://gist.github.com/emres/67b4eae86fa92df69f61#file-starterapptest-java-L47).